# What if the Community user doesn't make it in time to reject my suggested edit before another user rejects it?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Consider [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/393712) suggested edit of mine.

My edit conflicted with heemayl's concurrent edit, which was applied immediately since he had more than 2000 reputation.

So at the time of the review, since my edit only addressed the readability of the code, while heemayl's addressed the grammar as well, the first reviewer rejected my edit as "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.".

Eventually the Community user rejected it as "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284) answer:

> You submit a suggested edit at the same time as the original poster or a 2000+ rep user (20000+ in the case of tag wikis) or any moderator (in other words, anyone who has full edit privileges over the specific post). In that case, your suggested edit will be rejected by Community in favor of the fully privileged edit. Since the Community user does not provide a message when such an edit is rejected, it may appear as though the system has rejected your edit immediately, without warning. Don't worry! This has nothing to do with bans, or your profile being banned from suggesting edits. Just try submitting your edit again and it could make it to the review queue.
>
> In any case, suggested edits rejected by Community are not counted towards the suggested edit ban.

So this time everything went smooth, but the Community user took around 7 minutes to reject it.

**What if the Community user doesn't make it in time to reject my suggested edit before another user rejects it?**

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the timeline, I don't think it was heemayl's edit that caused the conflict, but OP's (which happened at 18:06, as did the Community rejection). I think your edit was submitted after heemayl's. While it was on a previous version, it is acceptable for an edit submitted on a previous version to overwrite another edit - edit often enough and you'll notice your edits getting overwritten by OP's edits. Did you notice a "post has been edit" message come above the answer?

Comment: I can't remember whether I saw a message or not (it's not a recent question), but something doesn't add up (in order): OP posted the question at 17:52; heemayl edited it at 17:56; I suggested the edit at 17:57; Galgalesh reviewed the suggested edit at 17:59 (and he rejected it because my edit was based on original question, not on heeymal's edit, and my edit was worse); What happened at 18:06? The edit looks exactly like the one I originally sent, so it looks like OP either approved it, aprroved and improved it without doing anything or rejected and improved it without doing anything

Comment: But in this case why does it looks like the Community user rejected it instead, and why with that message?

Comment: It looks like the edit conflicted with OP's approval of my edit like you said, but my edit was rejected instead. Looks like a bug, this shouldn't be the intended behavior